# Verification with single input

Tags: html, css

Trying to create an `input` for verification code with single input not four. but I got some problems:

1. input not clickable correctly, it kinda buggy and you need to click end of input to type something
2. how can I sync dashes with entered numbers that work with all numbers and always be in center and under each numbers, is there any trick?
3. any suggestion and best practice?

```css
input {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ededed;
    outline: unset !important;
    letter-spacing: 80px;
    text-indent: 105px;
}
.verf {
position: relative;
float: left;
}
.verf::after {
    content: "____";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 10px;
    color: orange;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 80px;
    text-indent: 105px;
}
```

```html
<div class="verf">
<input maxlength="4" value="4578"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi first problem is clear, but second, if you see, dash should exactly be under `8` or `7` or `5`, but it just under `4` , I want it work with all numbers that we enter, dashed should be exactly under numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `underline` as `dash` instead use `html` tag, and use `flex` to make those `center` and with some changes on `letter-spacing` and also `text-indent` you can achieve what you want. This can be a solution! but I think best practice is using multiple inputs.

```css
input {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  outline: unset !important;
  letter-spacing: 69px;
  text-indent: 132px;
}

.verf {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.dash {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 8px;
}

.dash span {
  width: 5%;
  height: 3px;
  background: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="verf">
  <input maxlength="4" value="4578" />
  <span class="dash">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you with what you want

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo code</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        #num1,#num2,#num3,#num4
        {
            width: 4%;
            outline: 0;
            border-width: 0 0 2px;
            border-color: white;
            text-align: center;
        } 
        #num1:hover{
            border-color: blue;
        }  
        #num2:hover{
            border-color: blue;
        }     
        #num3:hover{
            border-color: blue;
        }     
        #num4:hover{
            border-color: blue;

        }          
    </style>

    <center>
        <input id="num1" onmouseover="placeoverChange('num1')" type="text" name="num1" placeholder="1">
        <input id="num2" onmouseover="placeoverChange('num2')" type="text" name="num2" placeholder="2">
        <input id="num3" onmouseover="placeoverChange('num3')" type="text" name="num3" placeholder="3">
        <input id="num4" onmouseover="placeoverChange('num4')" type="text" name="num4" placeholder="4">
    </center>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function placeoverChange(id)
        {
            var plshldr = document.getElementById(id).placeholder
            document.getElementById(id).onmousemove=function(){document.getElementById(id).placeholder=""};
            document.getElementById(id).onmouseout=function(){document.getElementById(id).placeholder=plshldr};

        }
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```